# Implementing Cocoa Bindings pattern

Tags: cocoa, design-patterns, cocoa-bindings

I have a class MyImage, that have a NSAffineTransform member transform.

In my AppDelegate a have a NSMutableArray of images.

I have a MyView that draw the images from AppDelegate.images. So it must track changes in AppDelegate.images and redraw the content.

What is the best way to implement this though bindings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't mean bindings, or if you do you have misunderstood how bindings work and what they are for.

For an explanation read this post - [Manual binding in Cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528608/manual-binding-in-cocoa/5542109#5542109)

You need to use **KVO** to observe the array of images. You need to make sure you add and remove images from the array in a **KVC compliant** way.